# Get LightSwitch screen control collection

Tags: controls, visual-studio-lightswitch

Is there a way to get a LightSwitch Screen's controls collection?

Something as simple as:

```
Me.Controls
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you the screen:

```
Dim control = Application.Current.RootVisual
```

Although, most of the controls on the screen aren't named and need to be referenced by their textblocks in the visual tree.

Have a look at the following thread (user samneric1) where I had the requirement to hide one of the menu items on the screen....

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/lightswitch/thread/194b53eb-0e21-49a6-9312-c640bf53d659/

Steve